# What to do for DPRP is disabled while creating profile in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

1) I have created the object for PRPaymentProfile by passing merchant info like,
paypal_user_name,paypal password and signature

2) Using that object I am creaing the user profile using paypalHttpPostRequest method with the argument of 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile' and details of buyer's payment details

The above steps are working fine with paypal sandbox account. For the live I am getting  DPRP error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to signup for DPRP [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=xpt/Marketing/general/ProRecurringPayments-outside) . It is $30 per month in addition to the regular Virtual Terminal or Website Payments Pro monthly fees.